# Css 3 custom trapezoid

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

Hi ,
I need create div which would look like one on the provided image. Notice black and grey zones. I have been experimenting with css 3 but i was able to create only differently rotated trapezoid. Is it possible to create this only with css ?

EDIT: What ive tried was this

```
trapezoid {

    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 0;

}
```

It produces trapezoid which is nice but its differnetly rotated and i cant figure out how to rotate it 
[image]

Comment: what effort have you made? can you provide css that you tried? can you provide an image w/ more contrast?

Comment: @DanielA.White edits made

Comment: Have a look at here for css only shapes: -> https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#trapezoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `skew`'ed pseudo element for this. Something like:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform: skewY(2deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Another Approach would be:

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:90vw;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  padding-top:10px;
  background:gray;position:relative;
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:90vw solid transparent;
  border-top:10px solid red;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
  transform:translateZ(0);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it looks great. Maybe just one question is it possible to make the "border line" somehow smoother ?

Comment: Well i meant. now you can see "stairs " it isnt perfectly straight

Comment: @Ziker: Please see update. I've forced hardware acceleration by using translateZ

Comment: Great now its perfect answer thanks for extended help

Comment: Maybe one last question is it possible to make the red part transparent ? i mean yeah i can set color to transparent but then its just a basic rectangle

Comment: @Ziker: You would be best to go with the (updated) first option with skew, then :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a dummy div to make it behave as want that to rotate and make the tail visible

```css
#black {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(1deg);
  top: -95px;
}
#grey {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="grey"></div>
<div id="black"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your expected output:

```css
.main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
}
.inner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    height: 80px;
    left: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 80px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.inner::before {
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-top: 83px solid transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 66px;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Hope it helps.